# Information extraction, indexing and search of PDF, word and text documents with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB have a feature where I could store PDF, text or .doc/docx documents and search for them
or do a match between two documents on a keyword found in their content?

For example:

I might want to store one document called *'claim.txt'* that has values for
 *diagnosis code, short description, date and amount* in it.
I need to store another one called 'physician_diagnosis.pdf' that has, among other text, a matching short description in it.

I would like to issue query where I could find any document that has both matching date
and same diagnosis. (e.g. 'pneumonia', '12/12/2012')

Is something like this possible with MongoDB using just its API, or do I need to do some pre-processing?

If it is possible, would you please point me to the good example and documentation.

Comment: You need to convert PDF and .doc/docx to text and then use this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/

Comment: @Edmon, where you able to solve your problem using MongoDB? I am now reseraching if what you asked can be done in MongoDB? COuld you provide any documentation if you have found one? Thank you!

Comment: I found this as the closest answer: http://v.bartko.info/?p=463 HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your task is probably better suited to something like Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which has inputs for many different documents (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler). You will have to write some code to do the proper extraction though.

MongoDB is more meant for **structured** data - although we call them documents, we do not mean "PDF documents" or "word documents" here. It's just the generic format that supports nested field types that we call document, as opposed to a relational database row which doesn't allow for that.